# Where is a particular snap program located

Tags: snap, ubuntu-mate, opera

I installed Opera and found it is a snap program.

It's not listed in the Menu and a search for opera* found all kinds of listings.

How can I find where it is installed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Snap applications should be located in /snap/bin/

If the application does not show up properly in the Desktop Search or Applications Menu or equivalent used by your Desktop Environment, please file a bug report with the Snap author.